# TinyMce + Ajax File Manager + Codeigniter = Little Problem

Tags: browser, codeigniter, tinymce

OK, I'm using the following:

TinyMCE, CodeIgniter, and the [TinyMCE Ajax File Manager](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/). I can upload correctly and it looks pretty good. However, when I view the HTML (from TinyMCE), this is what I get.

```
<img src="../../../data/page/verde_enfemera.jpg" alt="" />
```

What I need to be getting is the following:

```
<img src="http://localhost/http/data/page/verde_enfemera.jpg" alt="" />
```

Can someone help?

EDIT: I changed the code in the HTML editor of Tinymce, then I saved it. When I re-opened it, the code was reverted back to the original "../.../../data", etc. please, help, someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the "relative_urls : true" to "relative_urls : false" under the options for tinymce. I'm a dummy.

Answer (score 1):

insert convert_urls : false

Answer (score 0):

Force TinyMCE to use absolute urls instead of relative urls by setting `relative_urls`, `remove_script_host` and `convert_urls` to `false` in the `tinymce.init` like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    ...

    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    convert_urls : false,

    ...
    ...
});
```